# How to move CertSrv from "Default Web Site" to a new site in IIS?

Tags: iis-7, ad-certificate-services

I have installed Active Directory Certificate services and it has created a CertSrv application under "Default Web Site" and it is accessible using http(s)://[hostname]/certsrv.

I want to move CertSrv from  "Default Web Site" and put it under a new site "CA" which I created manually and access it using http(s)://ca.my.local/certsrv (ca.my.local is separate from hostname).

I am unable to find a way to make it work, can somebody please tell me how to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

The /certsrv vdir is created when the "certification authority web enrollment" role is installed with the CA role. If you install "certification authority web enrollment" by itself on your ca.my.local server , it will create this vdir.